# WooCommerce My Account Shortcode

Tags: themes, woocommerce-offtopic, page-template

I'm running the latest version of WordPress (4.9.2) and WooCommerce (3.2.6) and I'm having issues overwriting the `My Account` template.

I've created a file in my theme:

```
theme-name/woocommerce/myaccount/my-account.php
```

I have a page in my `WP Admin` with the `post_content` set to:

```
[woocommerce_my_account]
```

However, when I open the link, `http://example.com/en/my-account`, it's showing the default `index.php`.

If I put the following code in my index, I get to see the account page:

```
do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]');
```

I've also made sure that my WooCommerce account page is set to the right one in **WooCommerce > Settings > Account > My Account Page**.

I can see in the body of the rendered page that has the following classes

```
page-template-default page page-id-8 logged-in desktop woocommerce-account woocommerce-page
```

Does anyone know why it's not displaying the page properly?

Comment: Can whoever down voted the question explain the reason? :thinking_face:

Comment: With "it's showing the default `index.php`" you mean the WooCommerce part isn't shown, but the regular page content is? Have you tried disabling all other plugins and using one of the default themes, without your modifications?

Comment: @swissspidy Yes exactly. Normally it should show the CooCommerce my account template instead of the theme's `index.php`.

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://example.com/my-account/`? What's your `WordPress Address` and `Site Address` settings in `Settings > General`?

Comment: I cannot get to reproduce this. Have you tried the debugging steps I mentioned above? Have you also tried removing the shortcode and manually writing it again?

Comment: downvoted since 1. WC is off-topic. 2. No code means that all answers can be no more than guesses. 3. Or in other words it is too localised and unlikely to be figured out without access to your server. 4. You put a bounty therefor the question can not be closed and the only avanue available is to downvote it (and please spare me the "but there are WC questions around here" argument)

Answer (score 0):

so `do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]');` is working in index.php and `[woocommerce_my_account]` is not working normal `wp admin` page.

have you tried looking for the issue with `the_content()` function? check if the loop is correct in your theme's template file.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have checked one of the following things:

1. Have you mentioned theme support for woocommerce in your theme? `add_theme_support('woocommerce')`
2. in dashboard go to `status` submenu inside `woocommerce` menu and check `template overrides` block if it is showing your template
3. Please make sure on your page template, there is `the_content()` being called inside the loop.

Thanks!

Comment: `add_theme_support('woocommerce')` shouldn't be needed. I successfully tested this without it.

Comment: @swissspidy you are right... it's just for letting WordPress know that theme supports Woo Commerce

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem it is not related to the shortcode or page template or index.php. It should work regardless.

I see you have a multilingual setup. You should look into how WooCommerce plays with this as it is not always easy. Most translation plugins (like WPML) have special helper plugin that ensures WooCommerce is playing nice with them.

Answer (score -2):

You should use **echo** when using `do_shortcode`. Change it to :

```
echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]');
```

You can check more info about `do_shortcode` here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/ . Cheers!

Comment: That's not the problem at hand. They demonstrated that using `do_shortcode()` works. The bug is that the My Account page isn't working automatically.